# Actionbar tabs are repeating during switching between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar-compat

Navigation drawer contains 4 items and each item contains 4 actionbar tabs ,while switching between menu items means if i click on menu item 2 then number of actionbar items changing to 8 and if i click on menu item3 then number of actionbar tabs changing to 12 ,how o stop this repeation of tabs.here is my code

public class TopicsFragment extends Fragment {

```
public TopicsFragment() {
}

// Declare Tab Variable
    ActionBar.Tab AllTopics, NewContent, StaffPicks, Popular, Recommended;
    Fragment fragmentTab1 = new FragmentTab1();
    Fragment fragmentTab2 = new FragmentTab2();
    Fragment fragmentTab3 = new FragmentTab3();
    Fragment fragmentTab4 = new FragmentTab2();
    Fragment fragmentTab5 = new FragmentTab1();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup tabs,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_topics, tabs, false);

        ActionBar actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity())
                .getSupportActionBar();


        // Create Actionbar Tabs
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Set Tab Icon and Titles
        AllTopics = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.tab1);
        NewContent = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.tab1);
        StaffPicks = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.tab1);
        Popular = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.tab1);
        Recommended = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.tab1);
        // Set Tab Listeners
        AllTopics.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab1));
        NewContent.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab2));
        StaffPicks.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab3));
        Popular.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab2));
        Recommended.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab2));

        // Add tabs to actionbar
        actionBar.addTab(AllTopics);
        actionBar.addTab(NewContent);
        actionBar.addTab(StaffPicks);
        actionBar.addTab(Popular);
        actionBar.addTab(Recommended);
        return rootView;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That problem is that you are adding tabs constantly when you go back in your `TopicsFragment` which will call `onCreateView` again and executing the `adding of tabs` to the **actionbar** thus adding another set of tabs to the current tabs.

**solution:**

you need to check first if the number of tabs is zero in your **actionbar**.

**sample:**

```
actionBar.removeAllTabs();
if(actionBar.getTabCount() == 0)
    {
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Set Tab Icon and Titles
        AllTopics = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.tab1);
        NewContent = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.tab1);
        StaffPicks = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.tab1);
        Popular = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.tab1);
        Recommended = actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.tab1);
        // Set Tab Listeners
        AllTopics.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab1));
        NewContent.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab2));
        StaffPicks.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab3));
        Popular.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab2));
        Recommended.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab2));

        // Add tabs to actionbar
        actionBar.addTab(AllTopics);
        actionBar.addTab(NewContent);
        actionBar.addTab(StaffPicks);
        actionBar.addTab(Popular);
        actionBar.addTab(Recommended);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks,but if i'm shifting from one menu item to other tabs are not chnging means menu item1 contains 4 actionbar tabs and menu item2 contains different actionbar tabs(4).

Comment: @user3680244 delete the current tab and add the new tabs

Comment: @user3680244 see EDIT above. remove the tab before checking.